# How to check if any date from array is in date range?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, date

Hope you are all well.

I need to check if any date from array

```
var arrayDates = ["2013-07-26", "2013-07-27"];
```

is in date range of

```
var startDate = new Date("2013-07-10");
var endDate = new Date("2013-07-10");
```

I am really stuck and started to confuse myself. Can anyone help me with that please.

P.S. Dates above are for example, they will be dynamic.

Thank you!

Comment: Will you be using `Date` objects or just text strings?

Comment: Can you provide an actual example of your code? As written, `var startDate = 2013-07-10;` will be interpreted as arithmetic and return `1996`.

Comment: I will be using Date objects. Updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use real date objects rather than strings.

maybe have a look at using dateJs for parsing dates
http://www.datejs.com/

But really you need to iterate through the array of dates and check if they fall between the tick value of your start and end dates.

Try this:

```
var arrayDates = [];

arrayDates.push(new Date(2013, 7 , 26));
arrayDates.push(new Date(2013, 7 , 27));

var startDate = new Date("2013-07-10");
var endDate = new Date("2013-07-10");

for(i = 0; i < arrayDates.length; i++){
if(arrayDates[i] >= startDate &&   arrayDates[i] <= endDate) {
   alert('Yes');
 }
}
```

Comment: I can't use any external libraries... Any code example how to "iterate through the array of dates and check if they fall between the tick value of your start and end dates"? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

After you have the date objects you can compare them in a pretty straight forward way. See this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp) at the bottom.

I see your question is tagged jquery, so you could do something like this:

```
$.each(arrayDates, function(i, val) {
    if (val > endDate || val < startDate)
    {
        //Date is outside of that range
    }
});
```

Comment: What is "date" stands for?

Comment: Oops, sorry. That should real "val" - I've edited my response

Answer (score 3):

Another method - http://jsfiddle.net/Mh5vn/

```
var ds = ["2013-07-26", "2013-07-27"];

Array.prototype.between = function(arg) {
    var d1 = new Date(this[0]),
        d2 = new Date(this[1]),
        d3 = new Date(arg);

    return (d1.getTime() <= d3.getTime() && d3.getTime() <= d2.getTime());
}

console.log( ds.between('2013-07-26') );
// true

console.log( ds.between('2013-07-28') );
// false
```

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you can convert these dates to numbers and compare them, here an example :

```
var arrayDates = ["2013-07-26", "2013-07-27"];

var unDash = function (string) {

    return string.replace(/-/g, "")

}

var dateInRange = function (date, startDate, endDate) {

    date = unDash(date)
    startDate = unDash(startDate)
    endDate = unDash(endDate)

    return date > startDate && date < endDate

}

// You now filter your array to retrieve your dates
var dates = arrayDates.filter(function (date) {

    return dateInRange(date, '2013-07-10', '2013-07-31')

})
```